# Inject SQL query into PHP code

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can I inject the following into PHP? The page doesn't load with the below code.

```html
                    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO phpn_banned_ip (ip_address, reason)
SELECT host_addr, "Spam" FROM phpn_session
WHERE guest='1';");
```

Comment: Source: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Comment: Didn't knew :P , but one question why u have " " on Spam ?

Comment: The purpose behind this code is because I have forum spammers flooding my site resulting in slow performance. This code would serve as a protection against those that are not welcome.  I have labeled them spammers.

Comment: Ok, but do you need the quotes? You're writting "Spam" can you try Spam without quotes instead?

Comment: I looked right past that. Good spot @GOZK!

Comment: Try enabling error_reporting and displaying of errors, I'm sure there'll be an error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO phpn_banned_ip (ip_address, reason)
SELECT host_addr, "Spam" FROM phpn_session
WHERE guest='1';");
```

Change to:

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO phpn_banned_ip (ip_address, reason)
SELECT host_addr, 'Spam' FROM phpn_session
WHERE guest='1';");
```

(Changed to single quotes surrounding Spam)